# Update all fields to journal table after each update

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, journaling

I have this trigger to update a single field in a journal table after each update, but I need to update ALL columns in related row in journal at once, not by naming each of them and separating by comma, how can I do that?

```
    DELIMITER //
    CREATE TRIGGER sfo_clone_update_subtotal_invoiced AFTER UPDATE ON sales_flat_order
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        update sales_flat_order_journal set subtotal_invoiced=NEW.subtotal_invoiced where entity_id=new.entity_id;
    END;
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: You have to update each value separately.

Comment: `set subtotal_invoiced=NEW.subtotal_invoiced, column2 = ???, column3 = ???...` for all the columns you wan to update

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE syntax allows you to set multiple columns, separated by commas.

```
update sales_flat_order_journal 
set subtotal_invoiced = NEW.subtotal_invoiced,
    other_column1 = NEW.other_column,
    other_column2 = (/* constant expression, not based on NEW */),
    other_column3 = (SELECT ...scalar expression from some other tables... LIMIT 1),
    updated_at = NOW() 
where entity_id = new.entity_id;
```

You can access `NEW.other_column` to get the values of the same row that spawned the trigger.

You can [DECLARE local variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-program-variables.html) in your trigger body to help calculate complex values.

You can use `SELECT` statements in your trigger body to query values from other rows or other tables, as long as you use a scalar `SELECT` that returns one row and one column.

If you need a more complex update that's too difficult to do in a trigger, I would do that in application code, not a trigger.

Comment: Thanks bill, is there any way to update all columns at once without naming all of them?

Comment: You would have to type in some expressions for what you want to update them _to_, wouldn't you? And then you ought to be specific about which expression goes with which column, right? Are you just trying to avoid typing?